# Infinite Carousel touch friendly that follows your finger, and works with div

Tags: html, carousel

I'm building an HTML5 mobile application that centres around having the main section of the page scroll through in an infinite carousel. It's gotta work for more than just images, it needs to work with text as well. The carousel also needs to follow your finger, as in you can drag pages left and right. To picture what I need, it basically needs to work like androids homepage, and flip back around to the beginning after it reaches the end. It also needs to be cross-platform.

I would prefer not having to implement an entirely new framework (like sencha touch, or jquery mobile), but I can do so if I have to, so long as it's self contained (doesn't conflict with the rest of my app, like by hijacking the DOM completely etc, sencha probably won't work)

I've evaluated a lot of carousel projects, but all of them so far are either not infinite, only support iOS, or don't follow your finger (or work with touch at all).

Does anyone know of any frameworks that satisfy this rather tall order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you could use dojo or jquery widgets for the carousel. Sencha touch is an awesome framework, and I would highly recommend it for an html5 mobile application.

Dojo Carousel
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mobile/Carousel.html

Jquery Horizontal slide
http://www.zackgrossbart.com/hackito/touchslider/

To make it endless you can just have a listerner that appends the data to the slider when you hit the end or near the end of the carousel.